# Can I use github pages to host a web page made with Spring framework(.jsp)? hosting github pages

Tags: spring, github

As it the title states itself,
I was wondering if I could host a web page using github pages, and the web page is made with Spring framework(.jsp files..).

Or to use gitgub pages, only web languages(html,js..etc) can be used?

Comment: No, you can't. github pages is for static web pages only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing can be executed on the server side on GitHub, beside [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions).

That means GitHub can only host the sources for your project, but cannot be a release/deployment destination.

For instance, [Heliohost](https://www.heliohost.org/#whitelist) might have a free tier allowing JSP deployment.